# How to build a hash table in matlab using coordinates as hash key?

Tags: matlab

Suppose that I have some data ordered as follows:

```
x     y     z     val
0     0     0     1
0     0     1     2
0     1     0     3
...
```

I am now using matlab and I want to create a hash table. The table should take the coordinate `x, y, z` as hash key and `val` as value. Could anyone please give me some hint on how to do this?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: Make use of [Map-Containers](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/map-containers.html)